# How can i comunicate my Angular 2+ frontend with my backend written in c++?

Tags: c++, angular, client-server, communication

I'm having some troubles finding a good way to stablish a communication between my frontend and my backend.

I have a C++ app that deals with the communication with some device, I'd like that my webpage gets the request from the user, then send that request to my always running C++ app, process that request, and then send a response back to my webpage, is there any way to make this happen?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use Boost Asio to build a REST server into your C++ app see:

https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/boost_asio/examples/cpp11_examples.html

Or you could use a C++ REST framework see:

https://github.com/Microsoft/cpprestsdk

There are a few others as well.

Finally you could build your REST/Web server using some other language such as Java or C# and use a messaging protocol to communicate to your C++ server. You could use sockets or ZeroMQ for example:

http://zeromq.org